# Chef:Install Apache at custom path/location

Tags: apache, chef-infra

I want to install apache using chef. But when I use:

```
package 'httpd' do
  action :install
end
```

It will install apache inside `/etc/httpd` but I want to install apache in another directory (for example: `/abc`).

Comment: `The Apache Software Foundation provides support for 300+ Apache Projects and their Communities`. If you are trying to install apache httpd server you can remote the tags of apache flink and Felix. Otherwise you can specify which apache framework you are trying to install.

Comment: I am trying to create a apache webserver 2.4

Comment: Please do some research and you can also post what you tried to achieve  your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom package and then installed in to desired loaction it helped me a lot Thank you very much everyone

Answer (score 0):

The Chef `package` resource uses the underlying system's package manager such as `yum`, `apt`.

You haven't mentioned the distribution you are running on. However, using `package 'httpd'` on YUM based distribution will trigger `yum install httpd`

So, first find how you can change/set the install path using the underlying OS command. E.g. for YUM:

```
yum --installroot=<path> install <package>
```

In a Chef `package` resource:

```rb
package 'httpd' do
  options '--installroot=/abc'
  action :install
end
```